# What are the possible reasons an array will repeat an index multiple times?

Tags: arrays, c

I am working on a program in C that will take the input of a temperature from a user and return a substance and boiling point if it is within 3% of that substance's BP.

I have currently run into 2 issues that I can't seem to solve.

1. The function `int find_substance(double value)` seems to skip and not print some iterations. I have it set to print the index to make sure the indexes are chosen properly.
   I checked each value on the table and the only ones that don't print are **-78.5, -35.5, and 3,280.00**.
2. Another issue at hand is when I reach the 8th index, **2,212.00**, it prints index = 9. Following this, each iteration prints index = 9, until I reach the last index where it prints nothing.

So what could cause an error like this?

I have checked the arrays to make sure there weren't any errors I missed and still have yet to find what is causing the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const char* name[] = {"Carbon dioxide", "Ammonia", "Wax","Water", "Olive Oil", "Mercury", "Sulfur", "Talc", "Silver", "Copper", "Gold", "Iron", "Silicon"};
const double temp[] = {-78.5, -35.5, 45, 100.7, 300.00, 356.9, 444.6, 1,500.00, 2,212.00, 2,562.00, 2,700.00, 2,862.00, 3,280.00};
int is_substance_within_x_percent(double temp, double value);
int find_substance(double value);
int main()
{
    double obs_temp;
    printf("Enter the temperature: ");
    scanf("%lf", &obs_temp);
    double value = obs_temp;
    int index = find_substance(value);




}
int is_substance_within_x_percent(double temp, double value)
{
    temp = abs(temp);
    if((value>=temp - (0.03 * temp)) && (value <=temp + (0.03 * temp))){
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
int find_substance(double value)
{
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<13;i++)
    {
        if(is_substance_within_x_percent(temp[i], value) == 1){
            printf("index: %d", i);
            break;
        }

    }
    return i;
    if (is_substance_within_x_percent(temp[i], value)== -1){
        printf("No substance was found.\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you don't need the `value` variable in the `main` function, use `abs_temp` in the call directly. Secondly, the `return` statement returns *immediately*, no statements in the function will execute after it. Thirdly, the `is_substance_within_x_percent` function will never return `-1`. Fourthly, when the loop ends the value of `i` might be equal to `13` which means it will be out of bounds.

Comment: What input provokes the observed misbehaviour?

Comment: Lastly, if the loop ends with `i == 13` then you know nothing was found, so don't need to call `is_substance_within_x_percent` again. Or you can just `return` from inside the loop instead of using `break`, in which case if the loop ends then you don't have to check anything, you *know* nothing was found.

Comment: `is_substance_within_x_percent()` is incorrect for negative `temp` arguments.

Comment: One of the biggest problems is the use of `abs()`, which is an integer function.  By using it, you will lose any fractional portion of the temperature.  Use `fabs()` instead.  Be sure to `#include <math.h>`, and link with `-lm`.  That may explain your observed problem, since you're using it to check the value, and if the check fails, you skip printing anything on that loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In the string `temp[]` change the commas for numbers in the thousands to straight numbers as well as remove any extra zeros since the array is type `double`, making them unnecessary (ex. 2,562.00 >>> 2562).

Also in `is_substance_within_x_percent`: add `value = fabs(value)` and change `temp = abs(temp)` into `temp = fabs(temp)` since both of these variables are double and you want the absolute value of each before calculating.